# How to test a get/post api with mocha and chai using authentication

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am testing some get and post apis of my node js application using mocha and chai. So far, I have been running it in my localserver and the sample code for each of post and get api is given below :

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var db_model = require('../models/myproject.model');

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../app');
var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe('First POST', ()=> {
    it('This is the first post', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
    //chai.request('http://localhost:8000') //this also works
        .post('/data/myproject')
        .send(db_model)
        .end((err, res) => {
            //expect(true).to.be.true;
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);

        done();
        });
    });


});


describe('First GET', () => {
    it('This is the first get', (done)=> {
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/data/myproject')
        .end((err, res) => {
            //expect(true).to.be.true;
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);


        done();
        });

    });

});
```

Now, I need to run the above code from the actual server i.e http://myproject.webportal.com

My POST request will be passed following parameters :
1. id = "any_numeric_id"
2. name = "some_name"
3. authentication (username, password) is required.
4. content = {"k1":"v1", "k2", "v2"}  // basically json data

My GET request for the same will be having only #1, #2  and #3 of the above list.
Basically when I fire this url manually in the browser it looks like :
http://myproject.webportal.com/data/myproject?id=405&name=smith

How do I need to change my code to fit this requirement, I have gone through several links about this but getting confused and not able to get the result.

Can anybody please help me on this coding to give me a fair idea on how to do it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Making an actual API call during test is not a good idea as it will slow down your test considerably. This also makes your test cases dependent on the network and other things which are out of your control which is not the best thing for tests.

You can explore the idea of stubbing your request. One of the such tool is Sinon (http://sinonjs.org/) 

Considering you already know all this, you should post when you put an actual url  at chai.request('http://localhost:8000') and what error you get.

Comment: Can anybody please at least tell me that in the above post call how can I also pass few more parameters along with the db_model ?