# How to start two commands sequentially in node JS application

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have written some unit tests for my node js application using mocha-chai.
I want to start the node JS server and the test suite sequentially one after the other through the scripts property of package.json file.

My node version is 6.9.4.
The scripts look like below in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test":  "npm start && mocha"
 }
```

With this above configuration if I fire the command from my Visual Studio code terminal as 'npm test' , then only the server is getting started by the 'npm start' and no 'mocha' is getting executed.

If I change the scripts as below :

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www",
        "test":  "start && mocha"
     }
```

In this case after the server is started the mocha is also starting but it is giving error as connect ECONNREFUSED 120.1.1.1:8000. It also pops up the dos command prompt with the area where the application is residing. Even if I check in the browser at this point to see if the application is running or not, I find that the server has stopped running.

I have also vainly tried with npm-run-all and npm-run-series packages. 
Tried semicolon (;) instead of && but did not get the desired result.

Any help on this requirement would much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to start the server (I assume this is what you're trying) programatically in the tests themselves. This can be done in the `before` function of the test. You can stop the server in the `after` method. Here is an example from one of my tests:

```
  var server;
  var tempMongoDbUrl;

  before(function (done) {
    reqLogger.transports.console.silent = true; // Silent the logger.

    tempMongoDbUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
    process.env.MONGODB_URL = tempMongoDbUrl + '_test';

    delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../data/db.js')];
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../../app.js')];
    server = require('../../../app.js'); // same as "node app.js"
    done();
  })

  after(function (done) {
    reqLogger.transports.console.silent = false;  // Enable the logger.

    server.close(function () {
      process.env.MONGODB_URL = tempMongoDbUrl;
      mongoose.connection.close(done);
    })
  })
```

`server = require('../../../app.js');` starts the server and `server.close()` closes it.

Many people will not consider this to be unit testing, but integration testing instead. This is because it's testing several units (routing, server, controller function, etc.). But it's still testing and I think there is value in testing the endpoints like a client would. I haven't had any performance issue while running tests this way.

Comment: My testcases look like the ones I have given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886850/how-to-test-a-get-post-api-with-mocha-and-chai-using-authentication?noredirect=1#comment80721424_46886850 . Unlike your example which does a lot of things, I just used a simple one liner statement which just starts the server (i.e server = require('../app.js')  in my before block. However I am still getting ECONNREFUSED 120.1.1.1:8000.

Comment: `server = require('../../../app.js');` and `server.close()` is the important part. I have `mongoose.connection.close()` to close the DB connection started in app.js. I also rename the database connection to not touch the ordinary database. Could you edit your post with the app file? Why is the address in your error message 120.1.1.1? If the connection is refused there might be a server instance running already. Only one server should be running at port 8000 at any given time.

Comment: You can ignore the last sentence of my last comment. If I understand correctly you get the error message from the client side because the server isn't running. I assume you have something like `app.listen(8000);` in app.js. You can change it to `app.listen(8000, function() { console.log('started server'); }` to determine if the server started or not. Make sure you see *started server* before the tests starts running.

Comment: I could figure it out. Actually I am running the server directly with ./bin/www as shown in the scripts block above in my post. Hence I changed the statement as server = require('../bin/www')  to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: If I follow exactly the same code , for the after block I am getting error as "after all" hook:
     TypeError: server.close is not a function

Comment: As I already mentioned that how I am starting the server. It is directly from bin/www where the app.listen(8000) is written. How would  I stop the server in this case ?

Comment: You should make sure the server object is exported in bin/www. For example `module.exports = server;` at the end of it. When you do `server = require(...);` in the test file it will get the server object, which you have to store in a variable with correct scope so it's available in the after function. That's `var server;` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

When you define npm scripts you may have pre and post scripts run automatically.

```
"scripts": {
    "premyscript": "echo \"Run 1st\"",
    "myscript": "echo \"Run after\"",
    "postmyscript": "echo \"Run last\""
}
```

When you hit 'npm run myscript' > all will run